# Bulk update Datagridview with BindingList

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource, bindinglist

I have a `DataGridView` that binds to a `BindingList`, I have to update the datagrid every 5 seconds. The update can be adding, removing or modifying. The problem is that since I update the `BindingList` by item, the `DataGridView` UI is constantly updating to reflect the changes, the result is long processing time. I'd like to stop `DataGridView` UI from updating and only refresh the `DataGridView` UI when the whole update is finished.

I tried to use normal list as the binding source, and notify the `DataGridView` to rebind the source after the update is finished. But the problem is that the scrollbar resets after rebinding, so I have to remember the position of the scrollbar, however, the scrolling action is interrupted by this fix if the user is clicking on the scrollbar while update happens.

Comment: Could you change the individual models to not be INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @beattyac, could you elaborate point?

Comment: When binding, if your model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, the binding will be 'Notified' every time that item changes.  If you remove this individual property notification, you could then manually update the binding, whenever you see fit, rather than it happening automatically.

Comment: @beattyac I think `BindingList` still detects Adding and Removing even if no INotifyPropertyChanged is imiplemented

Comment: In that particular case, you could then use a List (or any other non notifying collection), and manually update your binding with something like: MyUIElement.GetBindingExpression(DataGridView.ItemsSourceProperty)
                      .UpdateTarget()